# downloading or getting support for a specific locale for TextToSpeech

Tags: java, android, localization, locale

**Problem**

I need to use TextToSpeech functionality in Android, but when I try to get set of Locales, only some of them are available like English, Chinese, etc. For me, I need Turkish locale.

Note: When I set the device locale setting to Turkish, and do required changes in code like `Locale l = new Locale("tr_TR")`, still this localization was not supported by device and got a warning.

**Question**

- Is there a way of downloading a specific language locale sources
  programatically in my application?
- Or is there another way of solving this problem (I mean getting
  support for let's say Turkish locale) in anyway different from downloading Turkish locale sources for TextToSpeech?